# Concatenating HTML with database entries?

Tags: php, postgresql, concatenation

Hey Stack Overflowians,

I have a beginners problem for PHP which I've not had too much luck searching for so I thought I'd ask.

The problem is a slight alteration of my past post which you can find via my profile (since it's my only one) where I'm trying to print data out of a database in a loop but also trying to wrap HTML around it.

In my example here, I'm trying to print the test line in my database which happens to be a style code of KO278 so that as well as printing the style code, it also prints it inside of an img src so the img of that item is printed as well but I'm not having much luck so far.

I thought perhaps some concatenation might work since I haven't used it much but my attempt at it didn't give me much of a result but perhaps my formatting could be off?

Anyway, I'm hoping you could aim me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Also, on a sidenote, I was thinking about if it would be possible for a small image of each colour (jpgs as they are more like patterns) to appear in place of the word of the colour but I don't see how I could link that up.

Some products have both mixed colours (so different jpgs of them crossing over) or up to 8 colours so I wouldn't know how to account for that much variability short of having a heap of fields in my database which doesn't seem very efficient. It's not that important but it'd be nice if anyone has any suggestions on how I might go about this?

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mc16koruproducts where collection = 'womens' order by ref";
    $result = pg_exec($sql);
    $nrows = pg_numrows($result);
    #print $nrows;
    $items = pg_fetch_all($result);
    #print_r($items);

    $type = '';

    for ($i=0; $i<$nrows; $i++) {
    if($items[$i]['type']!=$type)
    {
        print "<h2>";
        print $items[$i]['type'];
        print "</h2>";
        $city = $items[$i]['city'];
    }

    print "<div id='info-holder'>";
        print "<div id='img'>";
        print "<img src='products/";
            print $items[$i]['style'];
        print ".jpg />";
    print "</div>";
    print "<div id='style'>";
        print "Style ";
        print $items[$i]['style'];
    print "</div>"; 
    print "<div id='desc'>";
        print $items[$i]['desc'];
    print "</div>";
    print "<div id='size'>";
        print "Sizes: ";
        print $items[$i]['size'];
    print "</div>";
    print "<div id='colour'>";
        print "Colours Available: ";
        print $items[$i]['colour'];
    print "</div>";
    print "<br />";
    print "<br />";
    print "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: If you are just looking to add small metadata, try making a database field "enum" - so you can pre define your field to written values, or if you intend on having more than 1 value per column, use "set".

Comment: Ah ok. I'm a school student so I don't have too much experience but we weren't really taught how to properly use databases. When it came to field types, we were told to basically use serial for the reference field and anything else, just use character varying. I knew we should have learnt what other field types were since I probably could have avoided this problem. I'll go and search what exactly they do.

Comment: apologies, I thought you were using mysql for some reason - for postgres you need to define an enum first-- CREATE TYPE different_colors AS ENUM ('red','green','blue'); then set your field to "field" "different_colors", on the table. Then you can store those values.

Comment: Ah, right. I've got my new type set up but nothing appears in the values column so I'm a little lost as to why that might be. The syntax is all in correct order as far as I can tell. Also, I'm not too sure I follow how I might seperate out the different values if they are in a single field. I'm sure I'll figure it out though. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you're missing a closing single quote after .jpg

```
print "<img src='products/";
print $items[$i]['style'];
print ".jpg />";
```

Should be

```
print "<img src='products/";
print $items[$i]['style'];
print ".jpg' />";
```

I hope that helps. If not just let me know and I'll dig deeper.

Comment: Haha, I did pick up on that earlier but I most likely undid it when I was undoing when trying some stuff. Thanks for that but I still don't see any PHP being printed at all. I'm still stumped on my end as to what it might be but I wouldn't be surprised if it's something small that I'm just reading over.

Comment: Gotta love it when the problems are something so minor. I had a capital W for womens in the database...